# Can I format Strings in VB6 with rich text commands?

Tags: string, vb6, richtextbox

I need to add a string to an email in richtext format. I cannot format the text out of a textbox by selecting it as I usually do. Can I just modify the string? And how could I do that?

Currently the text was formatted in HTML but that isn't an option anymore. Looks something like this

```
string = vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<B><FONT face=Arial color=#365f91 size=2>" & _
                        strName & "</FONT>" & _
                        "<FONT face=Arial size=2><BR>" & _
                        "<I>" & strPosition & "</I>" & _
                        "</FONT></B><BR/><B><FONT face=Arial size=2>" & _
                        strAddress1 & "</FONT></B><BR/><FONT face=Arial size=1>" & _
                        strAddress2 & "<BR>" & strCity & ", " & _
                        strProvince & ", " & strPostalCode & _
                        "<BR>" & strCountry & "<BR>Office: " & strPhone & _
                        "<BR>" & strEmail & "<BR>www.website.com<BR>" & _
                        "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" & _
                        "<I><FONT face=Arial size=2>" & strImageCaption & "</FONT>" & _
                        "<BR/><BR/><BR/></I><FONT face=Arial size=1>" & strDisclaimer & _
                        "</FONT></P>"
```

I can't find any resources online about formatting rich text that isn't currently in a rich text box so I think maybe it isn't possible.

Comment: What do you mean by modify the string? it is an HTML format. try to save this html format as file and open it with RTF.

Comment: Well I'm in VB6 and I'm trying to open Outlook in RichText format. I was having problems with Outlook in HTML format but I need to add this info formatted the same. I want to change the code so the output is the same but it uses rich text commands instead of html. Is that possible?

Comment: VB6 is irrelevant to the formatting. It's just a string that is interpreted by Outlook. You can probably pass a string contianing rich text markup if it's set to rich text.

Comment: Do you know a resource on Rich Text Markup? I can only find people editting rich text boxes.

Comment: Check this bbcode to RTF sample: https://gist.github.com/wqweto/2225521